# Webview fails to render some page elements which have 100% width on Android 4.4 in landscape view

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, webview

Now I have already tried searching for any fixup but failed, Over the last two weeks I have been searching Google and other sites constantly for a way to make the elements in a webview on Android 4.4 scale up 100% when the screen dimension changes to landscape but there seems to be no hope at all.

I know this can also be accomplised by javascript but still when I point the google chrome brower to this test site, surprisingly, it does scale 100% right away but in my webview it fails to scale when I change the screen dimension from portait to landscape.

Actually what happens is that when I first load up the site or refresh it, it does well, but if I rotate the device to change dimension, some elements of this page are not affected by the css rule which is supposed to force them become 100% width of the device width.

However, Other android phones work as expected but  the point is that how does the Android google chrome browser work and scale well with the same site yet my webview is byfar equiped with what I assume the correct settings.

```
            webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
            webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e9ebee"));
            webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
            webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webView.getSettings().setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
            webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);




  webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
            //if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);else webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

            webView.loadUrl(home_string_url);
```

I need help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, is the drawing cache the culprit?

Comment: @Phix, Nah. It aint that cos I also get rid of it and still no change